# Python: How to convert a list of number in a nested list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of binary number like this:

```
['11100', '11010', '11001', '10110', '10101', '10011', '01110', '01101', '01011', '00111']
```

Is there a method to create a nested list containing sublists in which the elements are the single digit of the bynary number?

```
new_list = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For most purposes you can already treat it this way, as a string is a sequence which can be iterated over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension like this

```
>>> l = ['11100', '11010', '11001', '10110', 
     '10101', '10011', '01110', '01101', 
     '01011', '00111']

>>> new_list = [[int(i) for i in j]  for j in l]

>>> print(new_list)
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is this one:

```
oldlist = ['11100', '11010', '11001', '10110', '10101', '10011', '01110', '01101', '01011', '00111']
newlist = [list(map(int,list(x))) for x in oldlist]
print(newlist)
```

And gives this output:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Tank you! Very nice answer!